# Predicting service date

Tags: regression, prediction

If I had an automated system that pays my bills, but the website where I pay them won't tell me when the next bill will be available. What is a good approach of predicting the date of the next bill? I don't see a regression model here as a good approach. I believe it's better to get a simple statistical mean or median between bill dates in days, and then guess the next bill date as: nextBill = lastBillDate + mean. Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your data, so I can't say if your approach is good or not. But your approach does not cover weekdays. So I would apply [time series analysis](http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/time-series-analysis) methods predict the service date.

Comment: Week days are irrelevant here. I actually went for time series and it works fairly well.